# Compute improper integral: $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I know that the improper integral $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-1}}dx$ converges. I got there using the comparison test:  $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-1}}dx \le \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$, where the latter integral is convergent. But I have no clue how to compute the exact value of it, if it is even possible.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a simple answer?

Comment: Nothing really, I was just asked to compute it at the university, so I thought that I might be missing something

Comment: Compute it how? Numerically? Trapezoid ir Simpson's Rule? Use of [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function)?

Comment: You can simplify by using partial fractions with $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x+i)(x-i)$ and using [elliptic integrals](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/) to start.

Comment: For what it's worth, $I = \Im \left(F \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + i \log (2+\sqrt{3}) \, \Big| \, -1\right)\right)$, where $F(\varphi \, | \, k^2)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.